# How can I determine when a value across multiple columns changes to a different value?

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I have a data frame like the following:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | B | B |
| A | A | A | B |

I want to determine at which column the value changes from A to B. For example, row 1 changes from A to B at column 3, so I want the value for the switching point to be 3. If there is never a change from A to B for a row, then I want the value to be 0.

How do I do this?

Here is the code I used. It seems to work, except it produces more rows than there actually are.

```
    switch_points <- c()

# go by each subject to see when they switch values
    for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
      switch_point <- NULL
# check each column to see when the value changes from A to B
      for (j in 1:8) {
        decision_col <- paste0("ambiguity_decision_", j)
        if (df[i, decision_col] == "B") {
          switch_point <- j
          break
        }
      }
      switch_points <- c(switch_points, switch_point)
    }

df$switch_point <- switch_points
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## sample data
 df = data.frame(
  x1 = c("A", "A", "A"),
  x2 = c("A", "A", "A"),
  x3 = c("B", "A", "A"),
  x4 = c("B", "B", "A")
)
 
df
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
# 1  A  A  B  B
# 2  A  A  A  B
# 3  A  A  A  A

## solution
apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = \(x) {
  r = rle(x)
  if(length(r$lengths) > 1) r$lengths[1] + 1 else 0
})
[1] 3 4 0
```

The above method isn't tied at all to "A" and "B" - it looks for the first time the value changes at all.

If you would like to find the first "B" value specifically (as your code does), I would do it like this:

```
apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = match, x = "B", nomatch = 0)
# [1] 3 4 0
```

---

FYI, "growing" objects in a loop--as you do with `switch_points <- c(switch_points, switch_point)` so that `switch_points` gets longer each iteration--is a notorious anti-pattern in R. It kills performance even on moderately sized data. It is much more efficient to "pre-allocate" your output to the correct size from the start and filling them in is much more efficient. Here's a corrected version of your loop using that approach:

```
switch_points <- rep(0, nrow(df))

# go by each subject to see when they switch values
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  # check each column to see when the value changes from A to B
  for (j in 1:ncol(df)) {
    if (df[i, j] == "B") {
      switch_points[i] <- j
      break
    }
  }
}
switch_points
# [1] 3 4 0
```

Comment: That worked beautifully! Thanks for the advice about growing objects in a loop too.